# Acrobat: keyboard shortcuts to toggle page display (single page / two-up)?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle page display in Acrobat (Reader or Professional) from single-page to two-up? (And even from continuous to 'normal')

(I know the various shortcuts for changing magnification [ctrl +, ctrl -, ctrl 0,  ctrl 1, ctrl 2 and ctrl 3], but I often want to switch between two page and single page as well)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one, but you could navigate to the options with keystrokes..

Comment: @daniel: Windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts should be shown in the menus to the right of the menu option. As none are shown, the only shortcuts are:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> single page
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> two up

Comment: +1 for providing the one valid way to do this, but on my system (Reader (X) 10.1.2), two-page side-by-side is Alt+V, P, P, and continuous is Alt+V, P, C.  
Perhaps something like AutoHotKey could be used to provide a single-stroke solution?...

Comment: Wait, so not for adobe reader? I use Reader , hmm I guess I need acrobat, thnx!!!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively here is an autohotkey script:

Single page, Windows Key + S

```
#s::
send,!v
send,p
send,s
return
```

Double page, Windows Key + D

```
#d::
send,!v
send,p
send,p
return
```